# How to show a pop up message when someone clicks on my javascript link

Tags: javascript

This is my code to open a javascript link which I am already using and it is working great:-

```
<a blank="" href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('This is my affiliate url');" rel="nofollow"><img src="This is the image which I want user to click" /></a>
```

Now here I want to show a message box when someone click on this image. That means the url should also open when somebody clicks on the image and a pop up message should also show with my message.

You might have seen several coupon websites. Their affiliate link opens, and a pop up message shows the coupon code when somebody click on that.

I want to achieve the same thing with the above hyperlink. Please help me how to do that.

Comment: Somebody answer please, I am waiting for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the library **[sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/)**. An example usage for your use-case can be found below. On clicking the `<a>` tag, a new page will open, in addition to a popup on the page you clicked the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="https://google.com"
   onclick="showPopup()"
   rel="nofollow"
   target="_blank" >
     Click here 
</a>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPopup() {
        swal({
            text: "This is where the text will come.",
        });
    }

</script>
```